# How can we calculate solar and lunar longitude in java?

Tags: astronomy, computational-physics, software

I want to develop [panchangam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchangam) logically. So, I want to find solar longitude and lunar longitude.
Could you please help me to find the solar and lunar longitudes in java or any mathematical formula for those?

Comment: If you have *Mathematica*, I think it can give you the coordinates of the Sun and Moon at any time.

Comment: This site has an algorithm and code for the Sun: https://squarewidget.com/solar-coordinates/